# List Directory of files to text file sorted by creation date but don't show creation creation date in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I've been doing some research on this problem but I can't get my head around it to suit my particular issue.

I would like to create a text file of a list of files in a directory, sorted by date but I don't want the date to be shown in the file.
The code I have so far is:

```
#create list of clips to merge
save_path = 'downloads/'
ignored = 'test.bat','mergeclips.bat','draw.bat'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('downloads/') if isfile(join('downloads/', f)) if f not in ignored]

with open('downloads/clipstomerge.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in onlyfiles:
        f.write("file '%s'\n" % item )
```

This code ignores the bat files but lists everything else out to a text file in a format ready for ffmpeg to merge the clips. The format of the text file looks like this:

```
file 'ARandomClipName.mov'
file 'Butterflies.mov'
file 'Chickens.mov'
```

At the moment the files are sorted alphabetically but I would like it to be sorted by creation date. 
Does anyone have any ideas how I could modify my code to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this issue problem the following way using the os module's listdir() and getcttime() fuctions and list comprehension.  As follows:

```
combo = [(os.path.getctime(x), x) for x in os.listdir()]
combo
Out[42]: 
[(1549321055.8699787, 'AncmtNavSecLevPageResources_en.pov'),
 (1549321046.853063, 'AncmtNavSecLevPageResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321055.8855789, 'EcsNavSecLevPageResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321047.3054688, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources.pov'),
 (1549321046.8842635, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources_en.pov'),
 (1549321046.4942584, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321046.5254588, 'WebChatAvailResources.pov'),
 (1549321047.2430682, 'WebChatAvailResources_es_US.properties')]
```

now if you need to prevent the .bat files, you can use a condition:

```
combo = [(os.path.getctime(x), x) for x in os.listdir() if '.properties' not in x]
combo
Out[45]: 
[(1549321055.8699787, 'AncmtNavSecLevPageResources_en.pov'),
 (1549321046.853063, 'AncmtNavSecLevPageResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321055.8855789, 'EcsNavSecLevPageResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321047.3054688, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources.pov'),
 (1549321046.8842635, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources_en.pov'),
 (1549321046.4942584, 'GlobalNavFlyOutResources_es_US.pov'),
 (1549321046.5254588, 'WebChatAvailResources.pov')]
```

Then just sort your list using the sort() function (ergo combo.sort() in this case).  At which points you can just print the list in order.  Which should put your files based on their creation date.

***How to apply this to the original code***

```
import os
save_path = 'C:\Python37' #here you need to enter the FULL path for your folder
os.chdir(save_path)
combo = [(os.path.getctime(x), x) for x in os.listdir() if '.bat' not in x]
combo.sort() #will sort the index, which is the created timestamp


with open("targetFile.txt", 'w') as f:
    for file in range(0, len(combo)):
        f.write('file: ' + combo[file][1] + '\n')
```

Combo variable here contains the following:

```
[(1547253963.0511992, 'LearnPythonEx4.py'),
 (1547253963.0862029, 'LearnPythonEx5.py'),
 (1547253963.1162057, 'LearnPythonEx6.py'),
 (1547253963.137208, 'LearnPythonEx7.py'),
 (1547253964.490343, 'LICENSE.txt'),
 (1547253965.6564598, 'NEWS.txt'),
 (1547253966.5165458, 'python.exe'),
 (1547253966.5725515, 'python3.dll'),
 (1547253966.8515792, 'python37.dll'),
 (1547253966.9225864, 'pythonw.exe'),
 (1547253967.0145955, 'vcruntime140.dll')]
```

Example file contents:

```
file: LearnPythonEx4.py
file: LearnPythonEx5.py
file: LearnPythonEx6.py
file: LearnPythonEx7.py
file: LICENSE.txt
file: NEWS.txt
file: python.exe
file: python3.dll
file: python37.dll
file: pythonw.exe
file: vcruntime140.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't figure out how to do replicate that using my code, could you use my code as an example and modify that please?